# Howto understand first run of application

Tags: android, google-play

How can I understand that it's the first run of my application after installation. When my application is uninstalled and installed again, I want to check the purchased items from the market and make them available to user.

Answer (score 6):

An option:

1. When app starts check if boolean X is true in shared preferences
2. If not - this is first run:

   1. check purchased items
   2. store boolean X as true in shared prefrences
3. Else

   1. Not first run

Comment: What if user clears data of application. Application is still on the device but boolean x will be false.

Comment: That's true, but it isn't the normal usage. You may also implement a registration in some server, but this has cons too.

Comment: Actually i don't need registration. I will check purchased items when the user clears data. So clearing data will be like uninstall/install of application. Thanks..